# Regex replace pattern only if between curly braces

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a `':'` or a `'|'` with the chars behind until the double `}}` with an empty string `''` only if it occurs between double curly braces.

Example:

`s = "This is an {{example_string:default_or_none}} or {{some_variable|yeah}} of what I want and this should:be untouched"`

Should become:

`"This is an {{example_string}} or {{some_variable}} of what I want and this should:be untouched"`

I tried this:

`re.sub(r'(?<=\{\{\w*)[:\|](?=\}\})', '', s)`

But it does not work. And I also get an error:
`error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: The error is telling you that you can't use `\w*` in the `(?<= ... )` because `\w*` doesn't have a definite length--it tries to capture as many characters as possible. The look-behind that you are trying to use requires that the matching sequence have a fixed number of characters in it. You can eliminate this error by only using `\w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works even for the cases when you have multiple `:` or `|` inside the curly braces:

```
import re

s = "This is an {{example_string:default_or_none|other|filter:whatever}} or {{some_variable|yeah}} of what I want and this should:be untouched"
result = re.sub('\{\{(\w+).*?\}\}', r'{{\1}}', s)
print(result)
```

**outputs**

```
This is an {{example_string}} or {{some_variable}} of what I want and this should:be untouched
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `re.sub()`:

```
import re

s = "This is an {{example_string:default_or_none}} or {{some_variable|yeah}} of what I want and this should:be untouched"
print(re.sub('[:|]\w+(?=}})', '', s))
```

Output:

```
This is an {{example_string}} or {{some_variable}} of what I want and this should:be untouched
```

Comment: What would help if i had multiple pipes like:  `{{this|for|exaple|and|this}}` to make this `{{this}}`

Answer (score 0):

Typing on my phone but why not simply...

```
import re

s = "This is an {{example_string:default_or_none}} or {{some_variable|yeah}} of what I want and this should:be untouched"

p = re.compile(r"\{\{(\w+)[\|\:]\w+\}\}")

print(p.sub(r"{{\1}}", s))
```

Comment: How could i get rid of patterns like above but with multiple pipes and colons like `{{this|for|exaple|and|this}}` to '{{this}}' with the same logic? @justin_ezequiel